# Getting an entire page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, get, save

I'm using jQuery. Say I perform some searches using:

```
var acronyms=["fubar","snafu","gnu"];

$.each(acronyms, function(index, element){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/search?q=" + element,
    success: function() {
    }
  });
});​
```

Is there anyway for me to save the contents of the resulting page such that I can manipulate the data afterwards. Either the entire page content or page content plus html would be acceptable.

Comment: Considering the comments on answer from @thenetimp, can you detail what you call "save" and "manipulate"?
what do you really want to do with the returned page?

Comment: I intended scanning the document for a particular html tag and value, say "<p>x y z</p>"

Comment: thenetimp's answer is probably what you're looking for then, you can use .load() to load even a fragment of a page... which means jQuery can do the scanning for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the HTML of each page, and then dissect it and append it, and do as you please with it.

```
var acronyms = ["fubar","snafu","gnu"];

$.each(acronyms, function(index, element) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.domain.com/search?q=" + element,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            var $container = $("#container", html); // look for a specific element in the returned HTML
            $("body").append($container);
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all or part of a document. The jQuery docs have [examples](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: .load() is intended to load HTML into a DOM element, I'm not sure this is what is expected here

Comment: Depends on what he means by save I guess.  Does he want to actually save it say to the server, or just display it in the doc.

Comment: yep, that's what I thought too.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I meant display it in the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var acronyms=["fubar","snafu","gnu"];

$.each(acronyms, function(index, element){
  $.get('http://www.domain.com/search', {q: element}, function(response){

     //add `response` to some #output div 
     $('#output').html(response);

   });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('*').html();` should get you the whole page's HTML.